# list mysql databases using php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

My phpmyadmin have these databases and looks like this:

```
demo_db_1
information_schema
mysql
performance_schema
demo_db_2
test_db_1
test_db_2
```

How can I get a list of all custom databases?

Meaning: when I run a file test.php, I would like to see a list like

```
demo_db_1
demo_db_1
test_db_1
test_db_2
```

I don't want to connect to any database. Just want the list of all the created databases. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-dbs.php

Answer (score 5):

Call a mysql query with `mysql_query("show databases;");`

You can get list of the databases you have access to with:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

If you want to get the list for some other user than the user you're logged in as, you have to query the `mysql.db` table.

Comment: Your welcome, Just don't forget to mark this answer as `correct answer` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code :

```
<?php
    //mysql_connect('HostName','UserName','Password');
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    $database = mysql_query("show databases;");
    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($database))
    {
    $fetch[] = $data;
    }
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($fetch);
?>
```